# Checkbox is not working in expandablelisview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-checkbox

hi  I am working on checkbox in expandable listview but i am getting many problems.

Conditions in **Group checkbox**

```
  1. if user "checks" **Group checkbox** all the **Child** must get check.
  2. if user "Unchecks" the **Group checkbox** all the **Child** must get Uncheck.
  3. if user "checks" **Group checkbox** so all the **Child** wil get checked & if user  uncheck any 1 checkbox in the childrow(Out of 10 or more childrow) so group must get uncheck automaticlly.
```

Conditions in **Child checkbox**

```
 1. multiple selection
```

*Problem* :

```
 1. mainly in in child, if check the childcheck box & scroll many checkbox which i selected is getting automatically unchecked when SCROLLING.

 2. In **Group checkbox** Conditions  3rd point. i dont know how to do it.
```

How to do it.. if any one worked on this concept please post ur code.

If u want my code its here [how to do checkbox in expanablelistview (in groupview and child view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575652/how-to-do-checkbox-in-expanablelistview-in-groupview-and-child-view)

Thank you Please help me.. if u already worked on this concept.. Me just wasted 3day by by doing this concept.. But no use..

Comment: @MohitVerma How to do it any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this site](http://www.javaw.net/1177.html), it should help.